# Pandas Pivot Table Sort Index Level 1 Not "Sticking"

Tags: pandas, indexing, pivot-table, transpose

I know this is a lot, but I really cannot pinpoint what is causing the problem.
Most of this code is just to demonstrate what I'm doing, but the short end of it is:

- After reordering columns in a multi-indexed data frame (via
  transposing and other methods), calling `columns.levels` returns the
  original sorted levels instead of the new ones.

Given the following:

```
#Original data frame
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Year':[2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014],
         'Type':['A','A','B','B','C','C','A','A','B','B','C','C','A','A','B','B','C','C'],
         'Org':['a','c','a','b','a','c','a','b','a','c','a','c','a','b','a','c','a','b'],
         'Enr':[3,5,3,6,6,4,7,89,5,3,7,34,4,64,3,6,7,44]
        })
df.head()
        Enr Org  Type   Year
0       3   a     A     2012
1       5   c     A     2012
2       3   a     B     2012
3       6   b     B     2012
4       6   a     C     2012

#Pivoted
dfp=df.pivot_table(df,index=['Year'],columns=['Type','Org'],aggfunc=np.sum)\
.sortlevel(ascending=True).sort_index(axis=1)
dfp
        Enr
Type    A                       B                       C
Org     a       b       c       a       b       c       a       b       c
Year                                    
2012    3.0     NaN     5.0     3.0     6.0     NaN     6.0     NaN     4.0
2013    7.0     89.0    NaN     5.0     NaN     3.0     7.0     NaN     34.0
2014    4.0     64.0    NaN     3.0     NaN     6.0     7.0     44.0    NaN

#Transposed
f=dfp.T
           Year     2012    2013    2014
        Type    Org             
 Enr     A      a   3.0     7.0     4.0
                b   NaN     89.0    64.0
                c   5.0     NaN     NaN
         B      a   3.0     5.0     3.0
                b   6.0     NaN     NaN
                c   NaN     3.0     6.0
         C      a   6.0     7.0     7.0
                b   NaN     NaN     44.0
                c   4.0     34.0    NaN


#Sort level 2 by last column and transpose back
ab2=f.groupby(level=1)[f.columns[-1]].transform(sum)
ab3=pd.concat([f,ab2],axis=1)
ab4=ab3.sort_values([ab3.columns[-1]],ascending=[0])
ab4=ab4.drop(ab4.columns[-1],axis=1,inplace=False)
g=ab4.T
g
    Enr
Type    A                       C                       B
Org     a       b       c       a       b       c       a       b       c
Year                                    
2012    3.0     NaN     5.0     6.0     NaN     4.0     3.0     6.0     NaN
2013    7.0     89.0    NaN     7.0     NaN     34.0    5.0     NaN     3.0
2014    4.0     64.0    NaN     7.0     44.0    NaN     3.0     NaN     6.0
```

I know this was a lot, but I really cannot pinpoint what is causing the problem.
If you do:

```
g.Enr.columns.levels
```

The result is:

```
FrozenList([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b', 'c']])
```

My question is: Why is it not:
`FrozenList([['A', 'C', 'B'], ['a', 'b', 'c']])` ?

I really need it to be the second one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `MultiIndex` stores itself as a set of `levels`, which are the distinct  possible values, and `labels`, which are integer codes for the actual labels used.  Changing the column order is just a reshuffling of the codes, not changing the actual `levels`.

If you want the `levels` by the order in which they first appear you could do something like this.

```
In [61]: c = g.Enr.columns

In [62]: [c.levels[i].take(pd.unique(c.labels[i]))
    ...:   for i in range(len(c.levels))]
Out[62]: 
[Index([u'A', u'C', u'B'], dtype='object', name=u'Type'),
 Index([u'a', u'b', u'c'], dtype='object', name=u'Org')]
```

Comment: In another situation, I just just had to reset the index and it did the same thing for me. In this case, perhaps after transposing.

Comment: That is to say, I was using MatPlotLib to graph my data frame and it graphed it in the correct order, but the x labels were in the original, unsorted order. As a work-around, I used: xlables=g.reset_index().ix[:,0].unique().tolist()